# Eclipse doesn't use JUnit 4.10 Docs

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, junit4

Can anybody give me advice on why my eclipse doesn't use the junit-docs? I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers Juno Service Release 1 and the recent Oracle Java7 Version in ArchLinux.

thanks,
Andreas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using the same version of Eclipse and I found that the JUnit javadocs link was pointing to a broken URL: http://www.junit.org/junit/javadoc/4.5. To change this, do the following

1. In Package Explorer, right-click your project and select Build Path --> Configure Build Path.
2. Under the libraries tab, expand JUnit 4 and junit.jar.
3. Select the Javadoc location and click "Edit".
4. In the Javadoc URL section, change the Javadoc location path to http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/ or another version specific link.

Comment: For the latest Junit 4, this should work: [http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/)

Comment: Under some circumstances, you may need the **https** version of the URL. Otherwise, Eclipse still detects it as valid, but won't show any JavaDoc.